# Is there a way to generically implement a trait for objects in smart pointers?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Is there a way to generically provide an implementation for a trait for objects in smart pointers (e.g. `Box`, `Rc`, etc)?

Example:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait KindaEqual<Rhs = Self> {
    fn kinda_equal(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;
}

// Nice to have (still need to copy-paste for each LHS container)
impl<T, Rhs, WrappedRhs> KindaEqual<WrappedRhs> for T
where
    WrappedRhs: Borrow<Rhs>,
    T: KindaEqual<Rhs>,
{
    fn kinda_equal(&self, other: &WrappedRhs) -> bool {
        self.kinda_equal(other.borrow())
    }
}

// Best to have (handles both LHS and RHS containers)
impl<WrappedT, T, Rhs, WrappedRhs> KindaEqual<WrappedRhs> for WrappedT
where
    WrappedRhs: Borrow<Rhs>,
    WrappedT: Borrow<T>,
    T: KindaEqual<Rhs>,
{
    fn kinda_equal(&self, other: &WrappedRhs) -> bool {
        self.borrow().kinda_equal(other.borrow())
    }
}

impl KindaEqual for f64 {
    fn kinda_equal(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        num::abs(self - other) < 0.01f64
    }
}

impl KindaEqual<u64> for f64 {
    fn kinda_equal(&self, other: &u64) -> bool {
        num::abs(self - *other as f64) < 1f64
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert!(3.141592654.kinda_equal(&3.14));
    assert!(3.141592654.kinda_equal(&3));
    assert!(3.141592654.kinda_equal(&Rc::new(3.14)));
}
```

The above gives me the errors:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `Rhs` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 | impl<T, Rhs, WrappedRhs> KindaEqual<WrappedRhs> for T
  |         ^^^ unconstrained type parameter

error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:20:16
   |
20 | impl<WrappedT, T, Rhs, WrappedRhs> KindaEqual<WrappedRhs> for WrappedT
   |                ^ unconstrained type parameter

error[E0207]: the type parameter `Rhs` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:20:19
   |
20 | impl<WrappedT, T, Rhs, WrappedRhs> KindaEqual<WrappedRhs> for WrappedT
   |                   ^^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

I've read that adding an associated type might fix it, but this is undesirable as it would force usages of the trait to implement it as well.

1. Can this be solved without an associated type? (preferable)
2. Can this be solved with an associated type?

Answer (score 1):

```
      /-- everything here
impl<Types...>     Trait              for         Self
                     \-- has to appear here         \-- or here
```

As the [error message](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0207) puts it, `Types...` have to be constrained by `Trait`, `Self`, or predicates of `Trait` or `Self`.

If you're okay with copy-pasting for every LHS container, you could move the `Borrow` handling down to the function itself, like this:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait KindaEqual<Rhs = Self> {
    fn kinda_equal<R: Borrow<Rhs>>(&self, other: &R) -> bool;
}

impl KindaEqual<u32> for u32 {
    fn kinda_equal<R: Borrow<u32>>(&self, other: &R) -> bool {
        self == other.borrow()
    }
}

// repeat for all supported containers
impl<T> KindaEqual<T> for Box<T>
where
    T: KindaEqual<T>,
{
    fn kinda_equal<R: Borrow<T>>(&self, other: &R) -> bool {
        (&**self).kinda_equal(other.borrow())
    }
}
```